# Get parent folder of current file PHP

Tags: php

I've done quite a bit of searching for this, so I'm sorry if this is a dupe. 
Anyway, I need to get the name of the folder the current file is in. For example, I want to convert something like `example.com/folder/subfolder/file.php` to `subfolder`.
 My current code is `dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`, but that returns `/folder/subfolder` instead of `subfolder`. Thank you!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The simpliest way is:

```
basename(__DIR__);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php

Comment: @taylorcressy seems that the above answer was given before this one... also we don't really use magic constant

Answer (score 38):

You need to combine your existing code using `dirname()` with a call to [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$parent = basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

Answer (score 4):

`dirname()` used with `basename()` would work ... also this if you want to get them all:

```
$folders = explode ('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Now $folders would contain an array of all of the folder names.

Cheers.

Comment: If doing this one should beware of the empty element at index 0 that will result from a path that starts with `/`

Comment: @DaveRandom Another reason for doing tests before putting the code into work! :) But yeah if that is annoying someone I guess the only other way would be to use regex.

Answer (score 4):

```
$folder = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen.